# Being able to scrape a website's data for NBA daily leaders. But problem with MaxRetryError

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a program for class, and am struggling, it was somewhat working at one point, but I have a feeling I may have blacklisted myself, cause I'm getting a MaxRetryError when executing the code.

Max retries exceeded with url: /session/535f3b31b6b76ca10ea210f69675563e/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001EF4961E430>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'

I was wondering if my code will work on someone else's machine haha :D

So the jist of my code is that the user will be asked a date in the format yyyy-mm-dd then uses that date to find all the box scores associated with the date.

This is the function giving me grief.

```
def main(): 
displayNames(getStats(get_Games(get_Date())))




def getStats(list_link):
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.headless = True
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument("--headless")
  options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
  options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  options.add_argument("--dns-prefetch-disable")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
  driver.implicitly_wait(15)
  player_names = list()
  pts_scored = list()
  boards = list() 
  assists = list() 
  blocks = list() 
  steals = list() 
  for link in list_link:
     driver.get(link)
     player = 1 
     while True:
        try:
             print(player)
             player_names.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[4]/section[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[1]/div/a/span/span[1]'.format(player)).text) 
             pts_scored.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[4]/section[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[20]'.format(player)).text)
             # boards.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[4]/section[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[20]'.format(player)).text)
             # assists.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[4]/section[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[20]'.format(player)).text)
             # blocks.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[4]/section[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[20]'.format(player)).text)
             # steals.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[4]/section[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[20]'.format(player)).text)
             player = player + 1
             time.sleep(5)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            break
     driver.quit() 
  pts_scored = [int(s) for s in pts_scored]
  # boards = [int(s) for s in boards]
  # assists = [int(s) for s in assists]
  # blocks = [int(s) for s in blocks]
  # steals = [int(s) for s in steals]
  return pd.DataFrame(list(zip(player_names, pts_scored)), columns=['Name', 'PTS'])
```

I was just trying to test out points_scored before I went elsewhere, I have another function that basically returns the max of the dataframe to get the person to score the most points. Let me know if you need more code.

Also if I am blacklisted, was wondering if there is an nba_api I could use or some package in python that will do a similar thing, seems like there should be one made but I can't find anything besides season stats, etc. No daily leaders. I'm open to switch my course if needed.

Here are some examples of two examples for the links in the list_link
https://www.nba.com/game/bos-vs-cha-0022000911/box-score#box-score
https://www.nba.com/game/phx-vs-bkn-0022000912/box-score#box-score

Comment: If it worked at least once on your machine, it will on someone else's. You're being blocked by the site, for too many requests. You've said _"the user will be asked a date in the format yyyy-mm-dd"_ - where? It's not in your code. What is the value of `list_link` when calling the function?

Comment: And instead of incrementing the counter for the table rows `tr`, just search for all `tr`'s and loop over those results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didn't put the whole code in here, cause those functions weren't an issue, dang is there any way to get unblocked? I sleeped for 5 seconds cause I thought that would be enough buffer not to get blocked (but then again I was blocked before I put that there. And I don't want to go through all the tr's because some of that isn't valuable, but maybe your way would be more efficient.

Comment: You _are going through all the `tr`'s_ anyway. Just by incrementing the row number until you get an exception, instead of just looping them all - which wouldn't need an exception check. Whatever criteria you have for "not valuable" applies to your infinite-until-exception method as it would for "iterate over table rows".

Comment: ah I see what you are saying, so how would I implement that? and if I got blocked I wouldn't be able to get in unless I try from another PC? Also wouldn't I have issues going to the website manually if that were the case? I can add my full code here, if that would be helpful to you.

Comment: Lines like `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[4]/section[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/a/span/span[1]' (note the **s**) would then give you something to iterate over by doing `for row in ...:`. Don't post your whole code, just how you're calling the `getStats` function, with two example links for `list_link`. In any case, getting blocked for too many requests is not something anyone can help with. You can try setting a different Browser header but it's strange that it works manually right after that from the same machine.

Comment: yeah it seems like I may not be blocked after all, but it seems weird..cause the code runs for awhile and then breaks, and doesn't break immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an api. Just use the gameid and then you can parse the json however you wish. For example:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

#url = 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscorescoringv3'
url = 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoretraditionalv3'
headers = {
'Referer': 'https://www.nba.com/',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {
'GameID': '0022000911',
'LeagueID': '00',
'endPeriod': '0',
'endRange': '28800',
'rangeType': '0',
'startPeriod': '0',
'startRange': '0'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()

#away_df = pd.json_normalize(jsonData['boxScoreScoring']['awayTeam']['players'])
#home_df = pd.json_normalize(jsonData['boxScoreScoring']['homeTeam']['players']) 
away_df = pd.json_normalize(jsonData['boxScoreTraditional']['awayTeam']['players'])
home_df = pd.json_normalize(jsonData['boxScoreTraditional']['homeTeam']['players'])
```

**Output:**

```
print(away_df.to_string())
    personId firstName familyName        playerSlug position                 comment statistics.minutes  statistics.percentageFieldGoalsAttempted2pt  statistics.percentageFieldGoalsAttempted3pt  statistics.percentagePoints2pt  statistics.percentagePointsMidrange2pt  statistics.percentagePoints3pt  statistics.percentagePointsFastBreak  statistics.percentagePointsFreeThrow  statistics.percentagePointsOffTurnovers  statistics.percentagePointsPaint  statistics.percentageAssisted2pt  statistics.percentageUnassisted2pt  statistics.percentageAssisted3pt  statistics.percentageUnassisted3pt  statistics.percentageAssistedFGM  statistics.percentageUnassistedFGM
0    1628369    Jayson      Tatum      jayson-tatum        F                                      32:15                                        0.688                                        0.313                           0.526                                   0.105                           0.158                                 0.105                                 0.316                                    0.158                             0.421                             0.200                               0.800                             1.000                               0.000                             0.333                               0.667
1    1627759    Jaylen      Brown      jaylen-brown        F                                      34:50                                        0.682                                        0.318                           0.600                                   0.000                           0.300                                 0.100                                 0.100                                    0.200                             0.600                             0.167                               0.833                             1.000                               0.000                             0.375                               0.625
2     202684   Tristan   Thompson  tristan-thompson        C                                      25:39                                        1.000                                        0.000                           0.800                                   0.000                           0.000                                 0.000                                 0.200                                    0.000                             0.800                             0.000                               1.000                             0.000                               0.000                             0.000                               1.000
3     203935    Marcus      Smart      marcus-smart        G                                      30:22                                        0.364                                        0.636                           0.235                                   0.000                           0.529                                 0.235                                 0.235                                    0.294                             0.235                             0.500                               0.500                             1.000                               0.000                             0.800                               0.200
4     202689     Kemba     Walker      kemba-walker        G                                      29:29                                        0.471                                        0.529                           0.400                                   0.100                           0.450                                 0.350                                 0.150                                    0.000                             0.300                             0.250                               0.750                             0.667                               0.333                             0.429                               0.571
5     203095      Evan   Fournier     evan-fournier                                               19:48                                        0.333                                        0.667                           0.000                                   0.000                           0.000                                 0.000                                 0.000                                    0.000                             0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000
6     203953    Jabari     Parker     jabari-parker                                               11:33                                        0.667                                        0.333                           0.500                                   0.000                           0.000                                 0.000                                 0.500                                    0.000                             0.500                             1.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             1.000                               0.000
7    1630202    Payton  Pritchard  payton-pritchard                                               15:34                                        0.333                                        0.667                           0.000                                   0.000                           0.000                                 0.000                                 1.000                                    0.000                             0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000
8    1629684     Grant   Williams    grant-williams                                               18:49                                        0.000                                        1.000                           0.000                                   0.000                           1.000                                 0.000                                 0.000                                    0.000                             0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             1.000                               0.000                             1.000                               0.000
9    1630174     Aaron    Nesmith     aaron-nesmith                                                8:01                                        0.333                                        0.667                           0.000                                   0.000                           0.600                                 0.000                                 0.400                                    0.000                             0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             1.000                               0.000                             1.000                               0.000
10   1628436      Luke     Kornet       luke-kornet                                                3:25                                        0.000                                        0.000                           0.000                                   0.000                           0.000                                 0.000                                 0.000                                    0.000                             0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000
11   1629641     Romeo   Langford    romeo-langford                                                3:25                                        0.000                                        1.000                           0.000                                   0.000                           1.000                                 0.000                                 0.000                                    0.000                             0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             1.000                               0.000                             1.000                               0.000
12   1629682   Tremont     Waters    tremont-waters                                                3:25                                        0.000                                        0.000                           0.000                                   0.000                           0.000                                 0.000                                 0.000                                    0.000                             0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000
13   1629035    Carsen    Edwards    carsen-edwards                                                3:25                                        0.000                                        1.000                           0.000                                   0.000                           0.000                                 0.000                                 0.000                                    0.000                             0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000
14   1628400      Semi    Ojeleye      semi-ojeleye           DNP - Coach's Decision                                                           0.000                                        0.000                           0.000                                   0.000                           0.000                                 0.000                                 0.000                                    0.000                             0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000

print(home_df.to_string())
    personId firstName  familyName       playerSlug position                 comment statistics.minutes  statistics.percentageFieldGoalsAttempted2pt  statistics.percentageFieldGoalsAttempted3pt  statistics.percentagePoints2pt  statistics.percentagePointsMidrange2pt  statistics.percentagePoints3pt  statistics.percentagePointsFastBreak  statistics.percentagePointsFreeThrow  statistics.percentagePointsOffTurnovers  statistics.percentagePointsPaint  statistics.percentageAssisted2pt  statistics.percentageUnassisted2pt  statistics.percentageAssisted3pt  statistics.percentageUnassisted3pt  statistics.percentageAssistedFGM  statistics.percentageUnassistedFGM
0    1628998      Cody      Martin      cody-martin        F                                      31:02                                        0.778                                        0.222                           0.615                                   0.000                           0.231                                 0.154                                 0.154                                    0.308                             0.615                             1.000                               0.000                             1.000                               0.000                             1.000                               0.000
1    1628970     Miles     Bridges    miles-bridges        F                                      33:53                                        0.429                                        0.571                           0.300                                   0.000                           0.600                                 0.150                                 0.100                                    0.100                             0.300                             0.667                               0.333                             0.750                               0.250                             0.714                               0.286
2    1629023      P.J.  Washington    pj-washington        C                                      38:36                                        0.500                                        0.500                           0.364                                   0.000                           0.545                                 0.000                                 0.091                                    0.000                             0.364                             1.000                               0.000                             1.000                               0.000                             1.000                               0.000
3    1626179     Terry      Rozier     terry-rozier        G                                      32:39                                        0.500                                        0.500                           0.286                                   0.000                           0.714                                 0.238                                 0.000                                    0.238                             0.286                             0.667                               0.333                             1.000                               0.000                             0.875                               0.125
4    1628984  Devonte'      Graham   devonte-graham        G                                      31:40                                        0.214                                        0.786                           0.083                                   0.083                           0.750                                 0.125                                 0.167                                    0.000                             0.000                             1.000                               0.000                             0.833                               0.167                             0.857                               0.143
5     202954      Brad   Wanamaker   brad-wanamaker                                               24:17                                        0.833                                        0.167                           1.000                                   0.000                           0.000                                 0.167                                 0.000                                    0.000                             1.000                             0.667                               0.333                             0.000                               0.000                             0.667                               0.333
6    1629667     Jalen   McDaniels  jalen-mcdaniels                                               19:05                                        0.625                                        0.375                           1.000                                   0.500                           0.000                                 0.500                                 0.000                                    0.500                             0.500                             1.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             1.000                               0.000
7     202687   Bismack     Biyombo  bismack-biyombo                                               21:45                                        1.000                                        0.000                           1.000                                   0.000                           0.000                                 0.000                                 0.000                                    0.000                             1.000                             0.500                               0.500                             0.000                               0.000                             0.500                               0.500
8    1630176    Vernon   Carey Jr.  vernon-carey-jr                                                1:46                                        0.000                                        0.000                           0.000                                   0.000                           0.000                                 0.000                                 0.000                                    0.000                             0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000
9    1630208      Nick    Richards    nick-richards                                                1:46                                        0.000                                        1.000                           0.000                                   0.000                           0.000                                 0.000                                 0.000                                    0.000                             0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000
10   1630203     Grant      Riller     grant-riller                                                1:46                                        0.500                                        0.500                           0.400                                   0.400                           0.600                                 0.000                                 0.000                                    0.600                             0.000                             0.000                               1.000                             1.000                               0.000                             0.500                               0.500
11   1628997     Caleb      Martin     caleb-martin                                                1:46                                        0.000                                        0.000                           0.000                                   0.000                           0.000                                 0.000                                 0.000                                    0.000                             0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000
12    203469      Cody      Zeller      cody-zeller           DNP - Coach's Decision                                                           0.000                                        0.000                           0.000                                   0.000                           0.000                                 0.000                                 0.000                                    0.000                             0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000                             0.000                               0.000
```

Comment: awesome, I think this will work with the game Id's I will get in my parsing function and I'll pass it to the api but these are some weird stats, haha is there like pts, rebounds, assists, etc?

Comment: ya ya. Just need to alter the api url for other stats. I just assumed the `"Scoring"` had all that there, but obviously not. Need the `"Traditional"` stats. I left the othe rin there so you can see what changed